# Webpack dev proxy async bypass

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I want to proxy/not proxy requests depending of result of http request.
So tried something like this:

```
bypass: async function(req, res, proxyOptions) {
          const smth = await request(...);
          if (smth) {
            ...
          } else {
            ...
          }
        }
```

But as soon as I add 'async', I get 404 for requests.

**Original problem**: (If there are any other ways to fix this -- also welcome )
For now in my JS I have 2 different logins, one for real prod app another for webpack-dev-server:

```
if (BUILD_ENV === 'DEV') {
   window.location.href = '/login';
} else {
   window.location.replace(window.location.href);
}
```

This works nice, but looks bad. So when index.html is requested I want to make request to BE server and if it is OK return my local index.html, if it is 401 proxy request to BE [ and BE will redirect to external oauth login page].